# How to replace "\" with "\\" in python?

Tags: python, windows

How to replace "\" with "\\" in python(type string)?  I tried `line = line.replace("\", "\\")`, but it gives error `SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character`

Comment: \ is an escape character, use raw strings or double \: `line = line.replace(r"\", r"\\")` ... and this doesn't work... Hmmm.

Comment: `r"\"` is a syntax error

Comment: r"\" is specifically not allowed for some reason, so `line = line.replace("\\", "\\\\")` as answered below

Comment: @dirck: You can't end a raw string with an unescaped backslash. Oddly, `r'\\'` seems to produce a string with two backslashes (even though the first isn't actually escaping the second). So you could do `line = line.replace('\\', r'\\')`, or you just do `line =line.replace('\\', '\\\\')` and avoid the confusion raw strings ending in slash involve.

Comment: @dirck: The reason it's not allowed is that backslash still escapes the quote mark, even in raw strings. So `r"\"` is viewed by the parser as a raw string beginning with a double-quote, and then it gets confused when the *third* double-quote closes the raw string (`r"\", r"` is treated as one literal), and it's followed by `\ ` (which it thinks is a line continuation character), but then sees more on the same line after it.

Comment: @ShadowRanger weird...  Parsers are fun.  Thanks.

Comment: @dirck: Yeah... This is why C++ went with a customizable raw string prefix, so you *never* needed an escape, even for the quote mark; you just make the prefix something that doesn't appear in the literal; if you later need it in the literal, you just make the prefix/suffix more unique. The shortest form is `R"(stuff)"`, but if you need `)"` in the string, you just add extra stuff between the `"`s and their matching parens, e.g. `R"foo(I can )" all )" I )" want )" in )" here)foo"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace `\` with `\\` in a Python string, you must write `\\` in the Python string literal for each `\` you want.  Therefore:

```
line = line.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

You can often use raw strings to avoid needing the double backslashes, but not in this case: `r"\"` is a syntax error, because the `r` modifier doesn't do what most people think it does. (It means both the backspace and the following character are included in the resulting string, so `r"\"` is actually a backslash followed by a quote, and the literal has no terminating quote!)

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is working!

Answer (score 2):

In Python strings, `\` is an *escape*, meaning something like, "do something special with the next character." The proper way of specifying `\` itself is with two of them:

```
line = line.replace("\\", "\\\\")
```

Funny enough, I had to do the same thing to your post to get it to format properly.